# Lower and upper bound on real inner product with eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Assume $A \in R^n$ is a real positive definite symmetric matrix, then for any vector $x \in R^{n \times 1}$, we have
$$
\underline{\lambda} x^\top x \leq x^\top A x \leq \overline{\lambda} x^\top x
$$
where $\underline{\lambda} $ and $\overline{\lambda}$ are the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $A$.
I would like to know if it is correct also, for any $x,y \in R^{n \times 1}$ that $x_i y_i > 0$, for $i = 1, ..., n$, i.e.
$$
\underline{\lambda} x^\top y \leq x^\top A y \leq \overline{\lambda} x^\top y
$$

Comment: Shouldn't all those $<$ be $\le$?

Comment: $x=(1,10)$, $y=(10,1)$, $A=\pmatrix{0&-1\cr-1&0\cr}$, $\underline{\lambda}=-1$, $-x^ty=-20$, $x^tAy=-101$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the positive definite property of $A$.

Comment: looks like a variant of the rayleigh quotient

Comment: Does my answer answer your question, Venus?

Comment: Are you still here, Venus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=(2,3)$, $y=(3,2)$, $A=\pmatrix{7&-1\cr-1&7\cr}$, eigenvalues $6,8$; $6x^ty=72$, $x^tAy=71$.

Comment: thank you @GerryMyerson, so it is not a general rule.

Comment: Correct. You may, if you wish, choose to "accept" my answer, by clicking in the check mark next to it.